# Find element inside a PHP array, with grouping of numbers

Tags: php, arrays

I have a long multi-dimensional array, with groups of numbers counting up to 100 ... For example:

```
$list = ( 
  array('1-4','first'), 
  array('5-7','next'),
  array('8-10','third group'), 
  array('11-12','another group'),
  /* ... keep going up to 100 */
  array('94-97','almost done'), 
  array('98-100','first')
);
```

I have a randomly generated number, to figure out with line to output:

```
$num = rand(1,100);
```

I'd like to know how I would go about getting the # associated inside the array. So, if I rolled a 3, I could get the first array key (1-4), and be able to print out "first"  .... or if I rolled a 97, I would get the 2nd-to-last key for "almost done" (94-97). Is there a quick way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: 1. Use a loop to iterate. 2. Use `explode()` to parse the string. 3. `if()` 4. `return` or `break`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the following... and it seems to work. If anyone has advice on cleaning up the code, let me know... Thanks...

```
$dieroll = rand(1,100); // Final Roll
$numarr = array(); $j=0;
foreach ($list as $k => $v) {
    $strTr = $v[0];
    $nums2arr = explode("-", $strTr);
    for($i=$nums2arr[0]; $i<=$nums2arr[1]; $i++) {
        $numarr[] = $j;
    }
    $j++;
}

$roll = $list[$numarr[$dieroll-1]][1];
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this if the structure of `$list` is guaranteed:

```
 $randomRoll = rand(1,100);
 array_walk($list, function($ar) use ($randomRoll){
    $nums = explode('-', $ar[0]);
    (int) $lower = $nums[0];
    (int) $upper = $nums[1];
    if (($randomRoll >= $lower) && ($randomRoll <= $upper))
    {
        print($ar[1]); 
    }
});
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your lookup array into an associative one since there are no gaps from 1 to 100.  In other words, every random number will fall into one of the known groups by determining the greatest number that it is less than or equal to.

Don't use any functional iterators (e.g. `array_filter()` or `array_walk()`) because they will unconditionally iterate the entire lookup array.  Instead, use `foreach()` and `break` as soon as possible -- this is most efficient.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/OnDqB))

```
$list = [ 
  4 => 'first', // 1 - 4
  7 => 'next',  // 5 = 7
  10 => 'third group', // 8 - 10
  12 => 'another group', // 11, 12
  95 => 'huge chunk', // 13 - 95
  97 => 'almost done', // 96, 97
  100 => 'first' // 98 - 100
];

$num = rand(1, 100);
foreach ($list as $key => $group) {
    // echo "$num vs $key\n";
    if ($num <= $key) {
        break;                   // don't iterate anymore after finding group
    }
}
echo "Num = $num, Group = $group";
```

Comment: An associative array as suggested basically prevents the occurrence of overlaps or gaps. An upvote for that.
Given the small number of entries, for me the argument of effectiveness falls into the realm of micro-optimization.

Comment: It is the leanest, most concise, ditect, and resource-economical technique that I can think of.  This us what I would use professionally.

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses [array_filter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php). The result is again a 2-dimensional array with the elements that fulfill the condition of the filter function.

```
$filter = function($a) use($find){
  list($low,$up) = explode('-',$a[0]);
  return $find >= $low AND $find <= $up; 
};
$arr = array_filter($list, $filter);
```

full example:

```
$list = [ 
  ['1-4','first'], 
  ['5-7','next'],
  ['8-10','third group'], 
  ['11-12','another group'],
  /* ... keep going up to 100 */
  ['94-97','almost done'], 
  ['98-100','first']
];

//for a test is better to use a fix number
$find = 9;  

$filter = function($a) use($find){
  list($low,$up) = explode('-',$a[0]);
  return $find >= $low AND $find <= $up; 
};
$arr = array_filter($list, $filter);

echo 'Label: '.reset($arr)[1]."<br>\n";
echo 'Area: '.reset($arr)[0]."<br>\n";
echo 'Array-Key: '.key($arr)."<br>\n";
```

Output:

```
Label: third group
Area: 8-10
Array-Key: 2
```

As of PHP 8.0, solutions with [match](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.match.php) are also possible for this:

```
$num = rand(1, 100);

$group = match(true) {
  $num <= 4 => 'first',
  $num <= 7 => 'next',
  $num <= 10 => 'third group',
  $num <= 12 => 'another group',
  $num <= 95 => 'huge chunk',
  $num <= 97 => 'amost done',
  $num <= 100 => 'first',
};

echo "Num = $num, Group = $group";
```